# Example of seemingly equal float variables not equal

Tags: c#

Can anyone show me an example of two C# variables containing float values that "seem" to be equal but in fact are not. When I say "seem equal", what I mean is that they intuitively seem to be equal.

The reason why I'm looking for such an example is because I have code that compares two float variables for equality and Visual Studio is warning me that `Comparison of floating point numbers can be unequal due to the differing precision of the two values.`. I understand that float variables are not precise (here's a [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate) where this is discussed and explained very clearly) but I am failing to find an actual example where two values that seem to be equal are actually considered different by C#.

For instance, the first answer to the SO question I referenced earlier mentions that `9.2` and `92/10` are internally represented differently so I wrote the following code to verify if C# would treat them as equal or not and the result is that they are considered equal.

```
var f1 = 92f / 10f;
var f2 = 9.2f;
if (f1 == f2)
{
    Console.Write("Equal, as expected");
}
else
{
    Console.Write("Surprisingly not equal");
}
```

So, I'm looking for an example of `f1` and `f2` that "seem" to be equal but would cause C# to treat them as different.

Comment: Try summing a float that is irrational when expressed as binary.  A base 10 example would be 3,000 additions of 1.0 / 3.0 compared to 1,000.

Comment: `if (Math.Sqrt(2.0) * Math.Sqrt(2.0) != 2.0) Console.Write("Surprisingly not equal");` but it's `double`, not `float` (`Single`) example

Comment: @DmitryBychenko excellent example. Thank you. In fact, if you submit as an answer I'll make sure to vote it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't insist on `float` (`Single`) type, but actually want any *floating point* types (`Single`, `Double`) example you can try:

```
   if (Math.Sqrt(2.0) * Math.Sqrt(2.0) == 2.0) 
     Console.Write("Equal, as expected");
   else 
     Console.Write("Surprisingly not equal");
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the code below. *value1* and *value2* both represent *toSum* * 10, but they are not equal. At least on my working machine. Float type has especially low precision on large values.

```
const float toSum = 1000000000.1f;
const int count = 10;
float value1 = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    value1 += toSum;
}

float value2 = toSum * count;

var equal = value1 == value2;
```

Comment: This is interesting, adding the same value 10 times yields a value different than multiplying the value by 10. This is indeed counterintuitive!